# Convert Object to Associative Array in PowerShell

Tags: object, powershell, hashtable, associative-array

Background: I'm getting data in JSON format and have to use it with `Set-QADUser` (from the Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell) to update a user in Active Directory.

Just providing the data parsed from JSON to the cmdlet results in this error message:

> Unable to index into an object of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].

I can iterate over the object like this:

```
PS C:\scripts> $data.params | ForEach-Object { $_ }

Key               Value
---               -----
manager           CN=smith,OU=Employees,OU=People,OU=Department,OU=...
department        Department
company           Company
homeDirectory     \\\\win7x64gerald.testdomain.com\\jdoe
homeDrive         U:
primaryGroupID    1501
userPrincipalName jdoe@testdomain.com
```

But Set-QADUser expects the data to be in an associative array format (or Hashtable). Example from the Help:

```
C:\PS>Set-QADUser 'mycompany.com/usersOU/User1' -objectAttributes @{otherTelephone=@('555-34-67','555-34-68')}
```

I would expect to be able just loop over it as above and access the Key and Value parameter like this:

```
PS C:\scripts> $data.params | ForEach-Object { $_.Key }
```

But this just shows nothing.

`$data.params.keys` shows all keys, same with values, but I can't fetch a specific one by just appending `[0]`, and there is no get-method I can find.

So, how can I convert an object like this into an associative array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:

```
# Create empty hashtable
$params = @{}
# iterate over every key and add it to the hashtable
$data.params.keys | foreach { $params[$_] = $data.params[$_] }
```

Comment: Your comment in the code could be misleading. You are creating an empty HashTable, which I believe is your purpose so that fine. An 'array' as commonly referenced would be `$params = @()` to create an empty array.

Comment: You are right, that's what the documentation of the quest tools calls it. I edited the question and the answer to reflect the terminology better.

Answer (score 1):

maybe as simple as using [convertfrom-json](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx) ?

Comment: It does answer the question. Might be better just to include a small example. It is intuitive to most but not to all.